# CSS: How to make an animation with a unique first stage, then an infinitely repeating second stage

Tags: css, animation

I need to create an animation in CSS that when triggered (in this case by hovering) will not add the property "padding-left: 100%" on the first loop, then once the first cycle of that animation is complete, will add that "padding-left" property, and keep it for all subsequent loops. Any ideas? (I can't use JS at all).

Comment: Use two animations?

Comment: Use two animations with a delay on the second one. Your delay must match the delay+duration of the first one.

Comment: cheers, didn't think of that.